# Erro na execução de um algoritmo no pascal

Tags: pascal

Estou estudando o uso do CASE na linguagem pascal, mas quando executo aparece erro sintático `";" não esperado`, neste algoritmo:

```
Program Crianca_Esperanca ;
    var
    D: integer;
    valor: real;
Begin
    writeln('--------------------------------');
    writeln('        CRIANÇA ESPERANÇA       ');
    writeln('--------------------------------');
    writeln('    Muito obrigado por ajudar'  );
    writeln(' [1] para doar R$10 ');
    writeln(' [2] para doar R$25 ');
    writeln(' [3] para doar R$50 ');
  writeln(' [4] para doar outros valores ');
  writeln(' [5] para cancelar');
  read(D);
    case D of 
  1:valor:=10;
  2:valor:= 25;
  3:valor:=50;
  4: writeln('Qual valor da doação? R$');
  readln(valor);
  5:valor:=0;
  writeln('------------------------------');
  writeln('SUA DOAÇÃO FOI DE R$', valor);
  writeln('MUITO OBRIGADO!');
  writeln('------------------------------');
  end;
     readln;



and.
```

Answer (score 2):

Faltou um `end` ao final do bloco `case`.

O código correto ficará assim:

```
Program Crianca_Esperanca ;
    var
    D: integer;
    valor: real;
Begin
    writeln('--------------------------------');
    writeln('        CRIANÇA ESPERANÇA       ');
    writeln('--------------------------------');
    writeln('    Muito obrigado por ajudar'  );
    writeln(' [1] para doar R$10 ');
    writeln(' [2] para doar R$25 ');
    writeln(' [3] para doar R$50 ');
  writeln(' [4] para doar outros valores ');
  writeln(' [5] para cancelar');
  read(D);
    case D of 
  1:valor:=10;
  2:valor:= 25;
  3:valor:=50;
  4: writeln('Qual valor da doação? R$');
  5:valor:=0;
  end;
  readln(valor);
  writeln('------------------------------');
  writeln('SUA DOAÇÃO FOI DE R$', valor);
  writeln('MUITO OBRIGADO!');
  writeln('------------------------------');

     readln;

end.
```

Comment: Ele realmente compilou, mas ainda não executa a atividade desejada, é como se ele ignorasse os outros valores(1,2,3,5) e só trabalhasse em cima da opção 4.

Answer (score 1):

Para efeito didático fiz algumas mudanças ao código acima, que pode ser útil a quem está aprendendo Pascal.

```
Program crianca_esperanca;
    var
    D: integer;
    valor: Double;
Begin
    writeln('--------------------------------');
    writeln('        CRIANÇA ESPERANÇA       ');
    writeln('--------------------------------');
    writeln('    Muito obrigado por ajudar'  );
    writeln(' [1] para doar R$10 ');
    writeln(' [2] para doar R$25 ');
    writeln(' [3] para doar R$50 ');
    writeln(' [4] para doar outros valores ');
    writeln(' [5] para cancelar');
    read(D);
    case D of 
        1:valor:=10;
        2:valor:=25;
        3:valor:=50;
        4:
        begin
           writeln('Qual valor da doação? R$');
           readln(valor);
        end;
        5:valor:=0;
    end;
    writeln('------------------------------');
    writeln('SUA DOAÇÃO FOI DE R$', valor:6:2 );
    writeln('MUITO OBRIGADO!');
    writeln('------------------------------');
    readln;
end.
```

> Para compilar (ex. Linux) Cole em um arquivo crianca_esperanca.pas
>   e a seguir execute: **fpc crianca_esperanca.pas**

Answer (score 0):

Acho que seja isso que você precisa:

```
Program Crianca_Esperanca ;
var
    D: integer;
    valor: real;
begin
    writeln('--------------------------------');
    writeln('        CRIANÇA ESPERANÇA       ');
    writeln('--------------------------------');
    writeln('    Muito obrigado por ajudar'  );
    writeln(' [1] para doar R$10 ');
    writeln(' [2] para doar R$25 ');
    writeln(' [3] para doar R$50 ');
  writeln(' [4] para doar outros valores ');
  writeln(' [5] para cancelar');
  read(D);
    case D of 
  1:valor:=10;
  2:valor:= 25;
  3:valor:=50;
  4:begin
        writeln('Qual valor da doação? R$');
        readln(valor);
    end;
  else
    valor := 0;
  end;

  if (valor > 0) then
    begin
      writeln('------------------------------');
      writeln('SUA DOAÇÃO FOI DE R$', valor);
      writeln('MUITO OBRIGADO!');
      writeln('------------------------------');
    end
else
    writeln('DOAÇÃO CANCELADA!');

    readln;
end.
```

Ao terminar o seu case você estava tentando ler o valor da doação sempre, quando na verdade só deveria ser lido caso fosse pressionado a opção 4. Outra boa prática é utilizar o comando else para o seu caso 5, pois, tudo que for diferente de 1, 2, 3 e 4 será ignorado. O if de maior que 0, serve para caso o usuário digitasse algum valor inválido.

Answer (score 0):

Substitua o `and.` que aparece no final por `end.`:

```
Program Crianca_Esperanca ;
    var
    D: integer;
    valor: real;
Begin
    writeln('--------------------------------');
    writeln('        CRIANÇA ESPERANÇA       ');
    writeln('--------------------------------');
    writeln('    Muito obrigado por ajudar'  );
    writeln(' [1] para doar R$10 ');
    writeln(' [2] para doar R$25 ');
    writeln(' [3] para doar R$50 ');
  writeln(' [4] para doar outros valores ');
  writeln(' [5] para cancelar');
  read(D);
    case D of 
  1:valor:=10;
  2:valor:= 25;
  3:valor:=50;
  4: writeln('Qual valor da doação? R$');
  readln(valor);
  5:valor:=0;
  writeln('------------------------------');
  writeln('SUA DOAÇÃO FOI DE R$', valor);
  writeln('MUITO OBRIGADO!');
  writeln('------------------------------');
  end;
     readln;



end.
```

Os blocos no Pascal, apesar de serem mais didáticos que um par de chaves (`{}`), ainda é um comando textual. Por isso o programador está mais sujeito a erros de sintaxe, principalmente no início.